# Is using C# for an embedded device that requires precisely timed TCP messages practical?

Tags: c#, tcp, embedded, compact-framework, windows-ce

Lets say I have a device running Windows CE and there are 2 options: using native c++ and using the .NET Compact Framework using C# to build the application.

I have to establish a connection with an external computer and send out status messages exactly every 0.5 seconds, with only a +/- 10 millisecond error tolerance.

I know you might say that in practice there are too many factors to know the answer, but lets assume that this has been tested with a c++ program, and works, and I wanted to make an equivalent program using C#. The only factor being changed would be the language/framework. Would this be possible, or would the 10 ms +/- error tolerance be too strict to achieve due to C# being a slower garbage collecting language?

Comment: 10ms isn't that tight, and embedded devices have fewer background operations running and interfering with your schedule.  Probably doable.  But do you have to hit that 10ms window 99.9999999999999% of the time, or is 99.999% good enough?

Comment: If you make it with a C++ program with 50% CPU utilization then you will get exactly the same result. If you have 90% CPU utilization with C++ you will still make it most of the time in C#. Is that good enough?

Comment: WIndows CE isn't a RTOS and that should answer the question.

Comment: I'd be worried about TCP/IP to start with.  The app (C+= or C#) can write to a socket every 50 ms, but after that you are at the mercy of the network to get that data to the destination.  TCP is reliable, but doesn't make any timeliness guarantees.

Comment: @BenVoigt probably the former % unfortunately :)

Comment: @Lundin So are you saying that regardless of language, I cannot expect to consistently achieve this on Windows CE?

Comment: @tcarvin good point but, I know that the network would be fast + reliable enough to deliver it fast enough. Famous last words I know but, I'm going with that assumption to make the question more answerable

Comment: @Gerhard sorry just want to make sure I get what you are saying since I am not 100% on your wording. So basically you are saying that I would have to make a C# program that only takes up 50% of the CPU it would have the same result as I would with c++. But, in the case that it takes up 90%, then it may start to be slower with C#, however even then it would still usually meet the +/- 10 ms requirement?

Comment: @honest230 Indeed. Windows CE is just for making GUIs and fluff. If you need it to give accurate timing "most of the time", then Windows can be used. If you need real-time performance and guarantees, you can't use it. If your requirement says "send once every 500ms, with at most 2% inaccuracy" and that requirement must _always_ be met, then obviously you can't use Windows.

Comment: @Lundin: Windows CE **is** an RTOS, but Win32 and .NET applications running on it don't have real-time characteristics.  Drivers *do*, and Windows CE primarily uses user-mode drivers, which being much much easier to debug than kernel-mode code make it a "programmer-friendly RTOS".  But not friendly to the level of magically giving application code real-time guarantees.

Comment: Interesting related article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms836797.aspx

Comment: @BenVoigt It doesn't matter what the drivers do, drivers are not even part of an OS. Can the OS guarantee that a certain piece of your code will execute at given time intervals?

Comment: @Lundin: If you have installed that piece of code as a timer interrupt handler, yes (or an interrupt handler for some hardware that is not exactly a timer, but still generates periodic interrupts.  For example, VSYNC interrupt of a display)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the specification arrises from ignorance of the fact that TCP's *data* reliability guarantee is the antithesis of *timing* reliability.

Answer (score 0):

The 10ms requirement would be achievable in C#, but would never be guaranteed.  It might be 10ms most of the time, but you can near guarantee a GC is going to happen at an inopportune time and your managed thread is going to get suspended.  You *will* miss that 10ms window.

But why does the solution have to be one or the other?  I don't know much about your overall app requirements, but given similar requirements, my inclination would be to create a small piece in C (not C++ because you want very fine control over memory allocation and deallocation) for the time sensitive piece, probably as a service since services are easy in CE, and then create any UI, business logic, etc. in C#.  Get the real-time nature of the OS for your tiny time-sensitive routine and the huge benefits of managed code for the rest of the app.  Doing UI in C or C++ any more is just silly.

Answer (score -1):

If your program does not need much memory and you can avoid long GC pauses then go with C#. It is infinitely easier to work with C# than C++. Raw C# speed is also pretty good. In some cases C# is even faster than C++.

The only thing that you get from C++ is predictability. There is no garbage collection that can surprise you. That is if you manage to avoid memory corruption, duplicate deallocation, pointer screwups, unallocated memory references, etc. etc.

Comment: _In some cases C# is even faster than C++._ You have a reference for that?

Comment: No reference. It was my own experiment few years back where I was comparing ~1000 lines of identical code that was purely CPU-bound with no memory allocation. Hash code calculations had to be tuned for faster calculations and in the end c# code was faster than compiled VS2008 C++ code. VS2013 C++ compiler was better and produced code that was faster than C# by a few percent. In general I consider algorithm as the main determining factor when it comes to speed. Programming language determines the development speed first and then execution speed second.

Comment: @Gerhard : C# JIT compilation is able to optimise for the specific platform it is running on - taking advantage of instructions that may not be available across all devices of a specific architecture, whereas C++ can only optimise for the target it was compiled for.  Often this is a generic lowest common denominator platform, so in theory, and in some cases C# can be faster.  C++ compilation for a very specific platform however is likely to be faster - but with the inconvenience of needing to be compiled for each specific instruction set variant or pipeline and cache architecture etc.

Comment: There is one more case when garbage-collected languages can be faster. If program is allocating and freeing a lot of small objects then garbage-collected language can finish task faster since it does not need to de-allocate every time object is no longer needed. Of course C++ can always be optimized but simple C# implementation can run faster than simple C++.

Comment: @OptionalOption - both will be slower than re-using the same fixed buffers, an approach which tends to be quite suitable for regularly repeated messages, as those tend to be of consistent (or at least bounded) size.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - you are right but I would expect performance difference to be a few percent at most.

Comment: Just alloc everything up front and never null it out